# Iteration outputting ONLY the last element of JSON array not all of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

EDIT - I apologize, didn't know it was an issue posting photos of the code. Replaced with real code.

I have a nested loop using forEach and it works as designed EXCEPT that when it gets to the array in the JSON names quotes it's only outputting the last element of that array.

Why would it be only outputting the last element and not the full array or at the least the first element? The last element has me a bit baffled. What I am trying to do is iterate and out put the Movie title and then output all of the quotes the movies has. Right now it's outputted 1 and it's the last element of the array.

BTW I know these are the quotes to the movies lol. I am using faker gem to generate the random quotes.

[image]

[image]

```
function renderMovies(movies) {
    movies.data.forEach(movie => {

        //Tag creations
        const movieUL = document.querySelector('#movie-list');

        const movieLi = document.createElement('li');
        const blockQuote = document.createElement('blockquote');

        const p = document.createElement('p');
        const footer = document.createElement('footer');
        const br = document.createElement('br');
        const hr = document.createElement('hr');
        const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

        //Assigning
        movieLi.className = 'movie-card';
        blockQuote.className = 'blockquote';
        p.className = 'mb-0';
        footer.className = 'blockquote-footer';
        movieLi.dataset.id = movie.id
        p.innerHTML = movie.attributes.title;
        movie.attributes.quotes.forEach(x => {
            console.log(x.sentence);
            footer.innerHTML = x.sentence;
        })

        //DOM actions
        movieLi.append(p, footer, br, deleteBtn, hr);
        movieLi.append(blockQuote);
        movieUL.append(movieLi);
        deleteBtn.innerHTML = 'Delete';
        deleteBtn.className = 'btn-danger';
        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => deleteMovie())

        function deleteMovie() {
            return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/movies/${movie.id}`, {
                    method: 'DELETE'
                })
                .then(movieLi.remove())
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: please post code as code, not images

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. Anyway, the problem is you keep overwriting the footer content here: `footer.innerHTML = x.sentence;`. You can start with using `+=` instead, which will append.

Comment: You need to craete a new `footer` element each time through the `quotes` loop, and append them each to `movieLi`. Or concatenate onto `footer.innerHTML` rather than replacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a loop for creating a list of footer tags and while adding them to the DOM.
This is the code:

```
function renderMovies(movies) {
    movies.data.forEach(movie => {

        //Tag creations
        const movieUL = document.querySelector('#movie-list');

        const movieLi = document.createElement('li');
        const blockQuote = document.createElement('blockquote');

        const p = document.createElement('p');
        let footerList = [];
        const br = document.createElement('br');
        const hr = document.createElement('hr');
        const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

        //Assigning
        movieLi.className = 'movie-card';
        blockQuote.className = 'blockquote';
        p.className = 'mb-0';
        movieLi.dataset.id = movie.id
        p.innerHTML = movie.attributes.title;
        movie.attributes.quotes.forEach(x => {
            console.log(x.sentence);
            let footer = document.createElement('footer'); 
            footer.innerHTML = x.sentence;
            footer.className = 'blockquote-footer';
            footerList.push(footer);
        })

        //DOM actions
        movieLi.append(p);
        footerList.forEach(el => {
            movieLi.append(el);
        });
        movieLi.append(br, deleteBtn, hr);
        movieLi.append(blockQuote);
        movieUL.append(movieLi);
        deleteBtn.innerHTML = 'Delete';
        deleteBtn.className = 'btn-danger';
        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => deleteMovie())

        function deleteMovie() {
            return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/movies/${movie.id}`, {
                    method: 'DELETE'
                })
                .then(movieLi.remove())
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. I added another let footer2 = [] but obviously that didn't turn out well lol Looking over your code make sense though. Much appreciated.